# TextView in RecyclerView not getting focused

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, textview, focus

I am adding a view that contains a RecyclerView to a ViewFlipper, but I am not able to move the focus to the list items within the recycler view and thus cannot select any list item. Could anyone please help?

This is my view layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="16dp"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/settings_item_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/main"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:divider="@null"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my row item layout which simply contains a text view and I have made it clickable/focusable.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

How you are setting OnClickListener?

If you set OnClickListener to contentView in your Adapter then remove clickable/focusable from your TextView. Or you can just set OnClickListener to your TextView(@+id/name) instead of setting it to contentView.

Comment: Do I need to set the listener for UI purpose? If I just want to see it's state change? I actually added "android:textColor="@color/color_text_view" to the textview, but I still don't see it gets the focus

Comment: I just tried adding android:onClick="onClick" but it doesn't solve the issue.